# The plugin didn't work on xcode 5.1

Tags: plugins, xcode5.1

I've updated xcode to version 5.1.
And all my plugins didn't work.

I didn't see any error log when I install them again.

How can I detect result of installing processing?

I'm using

- Alcatraz.xcplugin
- CocoaPods.xcplugin
- KSImageNamed.xcplugin
- XAlign.xcplugin

I think there's some problem with xcode 5.1 because all my plugins still work on xcode 5.0.1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I edited Info.plist file like this:

Add `A2E4D43F-41F4-4FB9-BB94-7177011C9AED` into key `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs`

It works for CocoaPods, Dash plugin. I'm trying with others.

Hope it works for you!

**Source:**
https://github.com/omz/Dash-Plugin-for-Xcode/commit/989b3aad46f5a30efacd7c23432ce7343d84cc58

Comment: Thanks so much! It works. But I dont understand what it mean. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 48):

Based on what Tuan Do said (THANK YOU!):

- navigate to your plugins folder (`library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`)
- Right click on the plug in and select show package contents
- Open the info.plist file and find the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs and expand that section.
- Click the + button and paste the UUID from above.
- Save the file and restart Xcode.
- Your plugins will appear again.

Repeat for any plug ins.

- Xcode 6 UUID
  C4A681B0-4A26-480E-93EC-1218098B9AA0
- Xcode 6.2 UUID
  A16FF353-8441-459E-A50C-B071F53F51B7
- Xcode 6.3 UUID
  9F75337B-21B4-4ADC-B558-F9CADF7073A7
- Xcode 6.3.2 UUID
  E969541F-E6F9-4D25-8158-72DC3545A6C6
- Xcode 7.3 UUID
  ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C

#### How to find the UUID?

Open Terminal and paste the following:

```
defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID
```

Comment: very good answer solved my problem in one minute.
thanks a tone

Answer (score 6):

You should add current UUID of XCode into plugin's DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs to make plugin work, use this command:

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -name Info.plist -maxdepth 3 | xargs -I{} defaults write {} DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`
```

1. `find` every plugin's Info.plist
2. `default read` current UUID of XCode
3. `default write` current UUID of XCode into plugin's DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple shell script that adds supplied UUID to all installed plugins:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "${HOME}/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins"
for plugin in *.xcplugin; do
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs: string $1" "${plugin}/Contents/Info.plist"
done
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AlexB thanks for the hint, won't make this mistake next time

Answer (score 0):

I've written an editor extension to solve this problem. Now you can fix this error by a simple click.

[image]

[image]

Download link: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbix1equ950zie9/FixXcodePlugin.unitypackage?dl=0)

Answer (score -1):

When that happens, quit XCode, open the Terminal and type:

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

then open XCode again. If there is a compatibility problem with any plugin, you'll see a log like this one:

*[MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID **C4A681B0-4A26-480E-93EC-1218098B9AA0** for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Lin.xcplugin' not present in **DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs***

So, what you have to do to fix compatibility problems is just add the logged UUIDs to broken plugins' Info.plist files, grouped at key **DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs** (in the example above, **C4A681B0-4A26-480E-93EC-1218098B9AA0**)

You'll probably be doing this at every new XCode version since Apple does not support plugins officially.